# Update the newly added added data from database to gridview without reload and ajax

Tags: ajax, gridview, signalr

I have a gridview which is displaying list of transaction, now i am using ajax to fetch the top 100 records every 1 minute, my requirement is to update the grid view either by adding the updated record to the gridview or total gridview load.

when ever a new record is added to the grid view or update one record it should be reflected in the gridview, how is it possible without using ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Signal R and SQL dependency to update table when database change happens. SQL dependency will notify server about change in database and SignalR can pass data to client side to update the table

Link for SQl dependency
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency

Link for signalR
https://www.asp.net/signalr